# Make first character lowercase and space underscore with regex

Tags: java, regex, pcre

I have this string:

`Fuel surcharge`

That I like to turn into

`fuel_surcharge`

using regex. My matching regex looks like this

`\b([A-Z])|(\s)`

and it gives me the two matches I need.

Then I try with this replace regex

`\L\1_\2`

With the logic that the first match should be changed to lower case and the second match should be replaced with `_`

But the result I'm given is

`f_uel_ surcharge`

I looks like I'm not able to isolate the second match. Do I need to enclosed the `_` in the replace regex?

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/t5ZPA0/1) is a link to the regex I tried on `regex101.com`. At the moment the regex is `pcre` but potentially I like to use it in `Java`.

Comment: How about just `s.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')`? Or, if you only want the first character to become lowercase: `s.substring(0, 1).toLowercase() + s.substring(1).replace(' ', '_')`?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. I'll use you solution if I implement it in Java. Now I got a bit curious how to solve it with just regex.

Comment: `\b([A-Z])([a-z]*)(\s)` to `\L\1\2_\3`

Comment: Java cannot change the case of text matched by capturing groups.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt For some reason that keeps the space, resulting in `fuel_ surcharge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\b([A-Z])([a-z]*)(\s)

\L\1\2_
```

as you wanted the underscore after the first *two* matches.